# Keeping different specific numbers of duplicate rows based on two Columns

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I have a data frame like this: [image]

I want to extract rows based on `Shape_Area` and `number_of_clusters`.

For ID_12: 9, `number_of_clusters` is 1. So, the row with `ID_12==9` that has the largest `Shape_Area` needs to be sliced. For ID_12: 73 there are 4 clusters but 5 observations. So the 4 largest observations based on `Shape_Area` would come in the resulting data frame.

I have tried this but it does not seem to be working properly:

```r
Map(function(x,y) 
  filter(mb_with_profile_f, ID_12 == x) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    top_n(y, wt = Shape_Area), sort(unique(mb_with_profile$ID_12)),number_of_clusters) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% group_by(ID_12) %>% 
  # sort by area in decreasing order for each ID_12
  arrange(desc(Shape_Area), .by_group=TRUE) %>% 
  # create a new column called rank that stores the row number
  # since we sorted in decreasing order by area, for each group, the row with largest area will have rank=1, and so on
  mutate(rank = row_number()) %>%
  # only take rows that have rank <= number_of_clusters
  filter(rank <= number_of_clusters) %>%
  # only select columns in the original dataframe
  select(names(df))
```